# Angular 2 - pass boolean "true" from one component to another (not siblings)

Tags: angular, boolean, components

On one component I have button that triggers function:

```
<button (click)="open Popup(); hideButton()"></button>
```

I have, lets say: `buttonService` that I should use for connection between these two components.

And in second component (which is not parent-child related to first component) I have multiple buttons like this:

```
<button class="element1"></button>
<button [class.hiddenClass]="hideButt" class="element2"></button>
<button class="element3"></button>
```

Second component is popup that is opening on same button click from first component and at that moment it should also trigger `hideButton()` function to pass boolean "true" to `hideButt` and hide button on that second (popup) component. How can i do it? With subscribe, Observable, EventEmitter?

Comment: As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50076798/1009922) and in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-ncaqw5), both components can access the same value in the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find the rxjs subject useful. It's great for cross-component communication with a service.
Add a property in your service class:

```
public buttonClick = new Subject<boolean>()
```

Then in the component you want to send the data out from, reach out to the service and call next () on it

```
this.myservice.buttonClick.next (true)
```

Then you can subscribe to your subject from any other component

```
this.myservice.buttonClick.subscribe (data => data)
```

And whenever you call next, any subscriptions will receive your new data from any component.

Also, a behavior subject is a subject that will emit an initial value

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can reach that using eventEmitter, it will notify your second component as soon as you click the button you just need to be subscribe to the [event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).

**Option 1 between components**
 You will do this in the component that you want to trigger the change

Import

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Declare

```
 @Output()variableEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Set value you want to change

```
   public sendChange(){

 this.variableEvent.emit(value);

}
```

Add this in the template of the component you want to receive the value

```
 <child (sendChange)="getValue($event)"></child>
```

Add this line in your component.ts

```
private getValue($event){
//Get the value
}
```

**Option 2 using a service**

```
  export class Service {
    public change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    public setdata(value) {

        this.change.emit(value);
    }
}
```

The component that set the data

```
export class SetDataComponent {

constructor(private service: Service) {}

private setData(){

this.service.setData(value);

}

}
```

Component that will receive the data

```
export class GetDataComponent {

constructor(private service: Service) {}

private getData()
{

this.service.change.subscribe(value => {
               let dataRecieve = value;

            });
}

}
```

The advantage of the event emitter is that as soon as the event occurs it will notify all the components that are subscribed.